# Need to make POST request through robot framework

Tags: post, robotframework

I am new to robot framework and I have a requirement to make a POST request through robot framework. I am able to successfully run the post request through postman tool. Below is the curl command which I generated through postman tool:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://ip:port/ai/data/upload \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data \
  -F 'fileData=@C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\report.html' \
  -F clientId=client \
  -F subClientId=test \
  -F fileType=compliance
```

Can somebody help me out with the equivalent of above curl request in robot.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It is expected that questions meet certain criteria. These are described in the [ask] page that I strongly suggest you read. In addition we expect a certain level of effort to already have been spent on your part. Although you provided us with the `curl` statement you want to mimic, there is no Robot Framework Code of what you've tried. This suggests to me that you may not have spent enough time on the problem yet and want just want working code. This is not what [so] is for.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex suggested you would like to have a look on 
https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests

Alternatively

store the command (curl...) in a command.sh file  and then execute this command.sh file through Process Library http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.8.6/libraries/Process.html

Code :

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process
*** Variables ***
*** Test cases ***
Test Requests
    test process
*** Keywords ***
test process
    ${handle}=    Start Process    command.sh     #make sure your robotfile and command.sh is in same directory or give path till sh file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Robot **RequestsLibrary** .

Here is the related link related to multi-part file upload case.

https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/issues/131

Try out this :

```
*Settings*

Library  RequestsLibrary
Library  OperatingSystem

*Test Case*
Test One
  &{data}=  Create Dictionary  foo=bar
  Create File  foobar  content=foobarcontent
  &{files}=  Evaluate  {'foofile': open('foobar')}
  ${resp}=  Evaluate
  ...  requests.post('http://localhost:8000/foo', data=$data, files=$files)
  ...  modules=requests
  Log  ${resp}  console=${TRUE}
```